# Java Generics with multiple Derived

Tags: java, static

I am fairly new to java and am a little confused by this behavior

```
public class MyBase<T> {
static int id;
}

public class DerA extends MyBase<DerA> {
}

public class DerB extends MyBase<DerB> {
}
```

I expect `DerA.id` and `Derid` to be TWO DIFFERENT `static` variables. But it seems to be sharing the same one!!! The behavior makes no sense to me - its 2 different types.

Comment: What does that have to do with generics?

Comment: [code formating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Generic Types in Java.  Should the title be edited?

Comment: it has everything to do with generics. Generics being sold as equivalent of templates in C++, seemed to me class1<int> and class1<char> would be different types and I would get 2 different class static members. I understand from TypeErasure in below comment thats not the case.

Answer (score 5):

The generics has nothing to do with this; Unlike templates in C++, you have only single class `MyBase` at runtime (it's called [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), so it has only single static variable.

`static` variables belong only to the class in which they are defined. Neither of the derivatives has this variable. What you want is called (in other languages, such as Smalltalk) *class variables*, and Java does not have such thing.

Comment: +1 ...and this question has nothing whatsoever to do with generics

Comment: Um .. isn't a synonym for "class variables" actually "static variables"?

Comment: @scottb No. in Smalltalk and Python, for instance, you have actually class variables and method, inherited/overridden and all that. `new` is such a class method in Smalltalk, and you can override it in the metaclass.

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that Joshua Bloch says that "static variables are also known as class variables" in Essential Java, 2nd Ed.

Comment: That's a misnomer used sometimes amongst Java/C#/C++ communities

Comment: @Elazar: Java has class variables and class methods.  In Java, you can also call these "static variables and static methods".  Neither requires an instance of the class (in the context of the JVM, both belong to the class object).

Comment: @scottb Is the dispatch dynamic or static? Can they be overridden?

Comment: @scottb Class method are method defined in a metaclass. Since Java has a single metaclass - Class - you cannot define such methods yourself, and cannot override them. You need an object hierrarchy of 4 or 5 levels. Not 3 as in Java. (Python does this "out of the system" AFAIK).

Comment: @Elazar: Java is a statically typed language, so most of the dispatches are static.  The particular overloaded method to invoke in Java, for example, is determined at compile time.  The dispatch of overridden Java methods occurs at run-time, however.  In Java, static members of a parent class may not be overridden.  This would not make sense according to the way that Java defines static members (which belong to the class object, not to an instance of an enclosing class).

Comment: @scottb A call to a simple non-private, non-final method in Java is dynamically dispatched; only the signature is determined at compile time. A call to static method is determined completely at compile time. So these are static methods (static as "compile-time-determined"), not class methods (class as "defined in the metaclass"). Since Java does not have the latter, you can call them "class methods" and be understood.

Comment: @Elazar: I'm not saying that your nomenclature is flawed or necessarily incorrect ... only that it is non-standard.  Every class in a Java app is instantiated at run time as a single class object (Class variables, which are reference types, refer to these class objects).  Static members which do not depend on any class instance are said to belong to the class object.  This is why, in Java, static members may also be referred to as class fields and methods.

Comment: So I will fix this to "called 'class variables' in other languages".  But now I think that the OP was actually confused with templates.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Class variables/methods exist in Java and are the same thing as static variables/methods. This is defined in the language specification...

Comment: @assylias is it still confusing after the fix?

Comment: Static members do belong to the class...the issue as I mentioned above is that X<int> and X<double> would be different types in C++ templates, in Java, the generics in accordance with your TypeErasure comments, is just a facade and you have one single type - therefore the class static would be a single one....

Comment: @excalibur This is what I say in the answer. My original argument is that static members belong to the class, but the OP expected was that they will belong to the metaclass (the same way that member funtions of an instance belong to the class, to be overridden by derived classes). Since Java has only single metaclass, this is not possible.

Comment: I have reordered the answers to answer the likely question first.

Comment: Elazar...agree with you. Your comment about TypeErasure basically answered my original question. Im not quite following however what the Class metaclass has to do with it. My question was about whether a generic actually creates a new class - seems no. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @excalibur Yes, but derivation has nothing to do with tje generic/templates question at all, and your example involves derivation.

Comment: Elazar - that was probably misleading but just showing what i wanted - to get 2 different static variable instances for 2 different derived classes by declaring it in the common base class

Answer (score 0):

Type variables do not apply to static context. For example you cannot do this either:

```
public class MyBase<T> 
{
    static T t;

    static void foo(T t){}
}
```